# how to draw a point(10,10) on QGIS raster layer?

Tags: qgis

I Have QGis complied code with mingw32 and i am using qgsmapcanvas class on QWidget, I am able to load the raster and vector layers properly on the widget i Qt.

Now, i want to draw some points on layer only not on map canvas, but whenever i try to draw points using qgsrubberband class let's say point (10,10), it draws onto the mapcanvas , but i want that point to be drawn on raster layer (10,10) position.